# How to check if a parameter is greater than (or less than) another parameter in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

So, there are these three parameters that I have in my template:

```
  DesiredCapacityASG:
    Description: Desired capacity for the auto scaling group
    Type: String
    Default: 3

  MinimumCapacityASG:
    Description: Minimum capacity for the auto scaling group
    Type: String
    Default: 1

  MaximumCapacityASG:
    Description: Maximum capacity for the auto scaling group
    Type: String
    Default: 5
```

I just want to validate whether `DesiredCapacityASG` lies between `MinCapacityASG` and `MaxCapacityASG`.

I believe this can be achieved using `CloudFormation Rules`, but there is no intrinsic function for greater than or less than.

I am aware that stack creation would fail if the desired capacity is not between min capacity and max capacity, but I don't want that, I want to validate the parameter itself, like if I wanted to validate my `InstanceType` parameter I would have done it like this:

```
"Fn::Contains" : [
  ["m1.large", "m1.small"], {"Ref" : "InstanceType"}
]
```

Comment: ASG will not allow the desired count to be set to outside of min and max anyway.

Comment: @jingx Ya that I am aware of but that will only happen after I've initiated stack creation, I want to validate in the parameter itself.

Comment: Use CDK or validate the parameters before calling CloudFormation?

Comment: Validate the parameters before calling - Are you suggesting to use Lambda functions? @jingx

Comment: Validate at what stage? You can't do this before you execute your stack.

Comment: Well these are parameters, right? If you must you could write some code to parse the parameter file and validate them before updating the stack.